# Problems with drivers for Nexus 10 when building Android 4.3 from source

Tags: rom-flashing, boot, samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung-nexus-10

I followed the steps in the [Android Source](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) web page to download **android-4.3_r1** and build it for Nexus 10.

**What is the problem?**

- When I download and install the drivers for Nexus 10 for Android 4.3 (JWR66Y) form the [drivers web page](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers#mantajwr66y), the device stucks at the Google logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Google put the wrong drivers in their drivers web page for Nexus 10 for Android 4.3 (JWR66Y).  You can get the correct drivers from this [page](https://github.com/pulser/vendor_samsung_manta). For more details, see this [post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2378405).